# How many times this function is being executed

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

```
def raiseToPower(base, exp):
    total = 1
    for count in range(exp):    
        total = total * base        
    return total

print ("returned from raiseToPower: %i" % raiseToPower(2,3) )
```

Does the for loop mean the time that the loop should be executed? If so, in the given case, isn't it should be executed (3-1) times instead of 3 times due to the constraint of range() function? Or is it executed in a sequence such as 0, 1, 2?

Comment: If you put a `print(count)` in the loop it would be pretty clear what is happening inside, also the function itself is executed once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop will iterate 3 times because there are 3 elements in range:

```
>>> exp = 3
>>> range(exp)
[0, 1, 2]
```